# Load product id from observer model and save to table

Tags: magento2

In my **observer** (for catalog_product_save_after event) i have loaded:

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $this->productUpdate($product);
    return $this;
}

public function productUpdate($product)
{
    $productId = 1;
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Queue')->loadByProductId($productId); 
}
```

**In Vendor\Module\Model\Queue**

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue');
}

//Problem here I want to load the product id and save the id to my custom table
public function loadByProductId($productId)
{
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    //$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue\CollectionFactory');
     $collection=$this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load();  
    $productid=$collection->getEntity_id(); 
    return $collection;

}
```

Comment: and what is the question here? what's the point of `$productid=$collection->getEntity_id(); ` ? Why do you use the object manager directly?

Comment: I was trying with objectmgr @Marius... Please suggest the proper code\

Comment: I get Call to undefined method \ResourceModel\Queue\Collection::addAttributeToSelect()

Comment: Any suggestions @Marius