# sql query in cms_block table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, cms-block

I have to write insert query for Magento 2 `cms_block` table,
for ex:-  `cms_block` table, what should i write for the column `created_in` , `updated_in` , `creation_time` , `update_time`

```
row_id  block_id  created_in  updated_in   title   identifier   content   
  254      254        1       2147483647  Designer  designer  "<p><span></span></p>"    

creation_time          update_time          is_active
2018-08-21 00:21:47   2018-09-18 01:00:07       1
```

These are the entries which are already there in `cms_block`, I have to create a msyql script insert queries so that i can run it on mysql console.
What does `created_in = 1` mean? similarly what is `updated_in= 2147483647` mean
looking at their data types they are `bigint(20) unsigned`.
for `creation_time` and `update_time` i will use timestamp, but what to use for `created_in` and `updated_in` in my sql query.

And if there is another approach to achieve that,
I looked on this link:-
[Magento 2: How to insert data into custom table in model file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105851/magento-2-how-to-insert-data-into-custom-table-in-model-file)

But my requirement is to run insert query on the MySQL terminal for 
Magento 2, and for that, I don't the meaning of two columns **created_in**, **updated_in** and if that's epoc time then how to do that in MySQL query

**UPDATE** 
WHEN I MANUALLY INSERT VALUE FOR ALL COLUMNS , following error occurs

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webster`.`cms_block`, CONSTRAINT `CMS_BLOCK_BLOCK_ID_SEQUENCE_CMS_BLOCK_SEQUENCE_VALUE` FOREIGN KEY (`block_id`) REFERENCES `sequence_cms_block` (`sequence_value`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`created_in` and `updated_in` are used for scheduled updates (EE-only feature)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mrg/ee/CmsStaging.html

`creation_time` and `update_time` have a default value (which is the current time) that will be set by mysql if you don't provide anything specific.

Comment: it gives me error in block_id column, ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'block_id' doesn't have a default value, row_id and block_id 'id' are same, how can i know what value to insert in block_id

Comment: and it also throw error for `created_in` and `updated_in` , ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'created_in' doesn't have a default value

Comment: you have to give values for both. created_in is useally 1 and block id is the block id